# In-App Purchase does not prompt for email

Tags: ios, in-app-purchase

I am trying to add an In-App Subscription to my app, but when I execute my code... or any In-App Sample.. I am prompted with a dialog that only asks for the password... NO EMAIL

The first time I tried my code it prompted for email but subsequent times it only prompts for password.  I deleted my app and have tried several sample In-App projects but they all ask for just the password.  I have reset the settings on the iPad but still only password. I have signed in and out of my Apple ID several times.  Tried it logged in and not logged n but I only get a password prompt.  Obviously I am new to In-App purchase code, but none of the samples prompt for email either.  I clearly am misunderstanding something.

What happened to the e-mail prompt?

Comment: "when I execute my code"  We don't see a single line.

Answer (score 2):

So I solved my problem with this.  It turns out there is an option in the settings.  If you tap the iCloud settings then choose iTunes & App Store, there is an option at the very bottom entitled, "Sandbox Account"

On my systems it was set to my REAL apple id.  I need to change that to the id from the dev site.

Hope it helps someone else with a similar issue.

Answer (score 0):

The best to test IAP is to use physical device with sandbox account credentials,
Steps :-

- Create sandbox credentials in iTunes, make sure every setup is correct.
- Remove all logged in account from the device by going through phone settings.
- Run the app
- And test with your sandbox credentials.

In simulator IAP won't work it always prompt the pop up when you launch the app asking password because you have logged with your apple credentials in your system.
It is taking Email from there. Resetting and relaunching is not a solution.
Follow above steps to test properly.
Thanks

Comment: Ok, got it, so #1 I have done, #2 I think is my issue, I am logged out of the iPad, do I need to do more than that?  I did read that I cannot use the test credentials to log in to the device, so I thought signing out in the iPad settings would suffice.  That does not seem to work so how do I remove the logged in account?

Comment: @LilMoke Account will remove from itunes if you press logout. After that run the app, and trigger the IAP purchase whatever you have did so far, If you have done correctly then on purchase delegate method you will get the pop up , over there put your sandbox credentials and try purchase testing. If you want better understading post here your with screenshots.

Comment: Hmmm, ok, I will try it all again, but I did log out, that is why I thought resetting the iPad settings would help.  I am not signed in to any AppleID on the iPad.  But I still only see the dialog asking for the password, wirth a cancel and buy button, no email text. box.  I think I am logged out because if I tap settings it says "Sign in to your iPad" on the top.